# Table simulation for lua

Tags: c++, lua, luabind

Good day

I have a specific task to give an access of c++ std::map to lua scripts. Desired script syntax is glob["tag"] = "value" or glob("tag") = "value"

In research, have tried luabind binding

```
std::string & glob(const std::string &tag)
{
    static std::string value;
    return value;
}

...

luabind::module(&state)
[
    def("glob", &glob, luabind::return_reference_to(result))
]
```

but after run of script listed below

```
glob("tag") = "asdasd"
print(glob("tag"))
```

got error [string "glob("tag") = "asdasd"..."]:1: unexpected symbol near '='

So, i'm waiting for your suggestions and opinions.

Thanks

Update
2lhf: Global variables data stored and serialized via c++ part and has to be accessed from lua. 
luaState is created per script execution, and doesn't exist between executions. One of solution is create and fill global variables table before script execution and sync it with map after execution, but, i think it is slow enough. So, access via c-function with mentioned syntax will be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`glob("tag") = "asdasd"` can never work, because it's not valid Lua syntax.  `glob["tag"] = "value"` can work. You need to set `glob` as a userdata with *index* and *newindex* metamethods. I don't know anything about luabind, so I cannot help you there. But doing it using the standard Lua API is not hard. I just wonder *why* you need to export C++ *map* to Lua, when Lua has excellent associative arrays already.

Answer (score 0):

Yep, metatable rules.

Just had to insert some c code get from samples

```
lua_createtable(&state, 0, 0);
lua_pushcfunction(&state, &getValue);
lua_setfield(&state, -2, "__index");
lua_pushcfunction(&state, &setValue);
lua_setfield(&state, -2, "__newindex");
lua_setmetatable(&state, -2);
lua_setglobal(&state, "global");
```

And everything works just fine, thanks

But here is another question: why i should use index == -2 for lua_setfield and lua_setmetatable?

Comment: Because the table is at possible -2, i.e, two positions down the stack, from the top.